# Would the static charge from a silicone work mat be dissipated by an ESD mat if placed on top of it?

Tags: esd, static, static-electricity, workbench

I know the proper rubber mats that are both ESD safe and heat resistant are quite expensive, and definitely out of the price range of a beginner hobbyist like me.  I have also read that the silicone work mats, while they are highly heat resistant, are insulators and can build up a static charge.

My idea is to buy a basic 2 layer ESD mat and a silicone mat to put on top of it, the theory being that any static charge built up in the silicone would be dissipated by the mat in same way any other static from the part being worked on or my hands etc. would be.  This would give me both ESD protection, and heat resistance.

Would this work?  I could get a silicone mat that is smaller than the ESD mat so that my hands are still brushing and being grounded by the ESD mat while I work.

Answer (score 1):

> *Would the static charge from a silicone work mat be dissipated by an
>   ESD mat if placed on top of it?*

Simply, no.

> *Would this work?*

Even if you put the silicone mat on top of a grounded metal sheet, it can still attract charge to the top side of the silicone mat. That charge is still an ESD problem.

Comment: Ah ok, is that because the silicone is an insulator, and therefore the charge can't 'move' from the top to the bottom?  What if I touched the top of the silicone and the ESD mat at the same time?

Comment: You would only discharge locally from that part of the mat.

Comment: @Tpw are we done with this Q and A session now. If we are then you should [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the motivation behind people giving their time for free to help others. I'm not asking for money, just question session closure by the recognized method for this site.